# How to dynamically define a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Is there a way to name or define a variable based on the value of another variable?

I have a MySQL result set in $row[1].

I am trying to dynamically name a variable by appended the beginning of a variable with the value of $row[1] as follows:

```
$sampleVar.$row[1] = 'a string';
```

But get this error:
`Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in...`

**More Info:**

I have these variables predefined:

```
$sampleVar01 = '';
$sampleVar02 = '';
$sampleVar03 = '';
$sampleVar04 = '';
```

The result of `$row[1]` will, in fact be either "`01`", or "`02`", or "`03`", or "`04`".

Comment: Don't do it.  Just use an array.  You will thank me later:  `$sampleVar[$row[1]] = 'a string';`

Comment: Not sure what you mean @AbraCadaver. My illustration and question was simply to find out if I could dynamically make up a variable, which (at)LucM helped me to achieve. My script and usage is way more complex than this simple example. Each of the $sampleVar99's are, in fact, arrays in and of themselves in my script. But for the very essence of my question, (at)LucM shows how to do it. Honestly, I was too deep in it and overthinking it. A fresh set of eyes from (at)LucM helped me to actually see the solution it so obviously. I appreciated his assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$var = $sampleVar.$row[1]
$$var = 'a string';
```

EDIT

After your edit, here's what you need to do:

```
$var = 'sampleVar' . $row[1];
$$var = 'a string';
echo $sampleVar01;
```

Comment: Ah, no I did not. But I will now @LucM

Comment: It did not work. I get this error `Notice: Undefined variable: sampleVar in`

Comment: Of course, your variables `sampleVar` and `$row[1]` must be defined.

Comment: see my "more info" in my OQ if that helps to answer my question ... "can this actually be accomplished".

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT @LucM. i'll try that now.

Comment: Brilliant help @LucM -- that was the answer. Now we just need to wait for "not-so-brilliant" SO to allow me to accept your answer as the answer. Thanks !!